# Simple term-archive-linked Taxonomy Entry output

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, list

I've registered a  Taxonomy named "type" and linked it to the Custom-Post-Type "group".

I simply want to output term archive-linked entrys of the Taxonomy "type".

Answer (score 0):

Found this code at the [official Wordpress Function Reference:](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)
A simple way to get all archive-linked terms of one Taxonomy.

> List all the terms, with link to term archive, separated by an interpunct (·):

```
$args = array( 'hide_empty=0' );

$terms = get_terms('my_term', $args);
if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    $count = count($terms);
    $i=0;
    $term_list = '<p class="my_term-archive">';
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $i++;
        $term_list .= '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '" title="' . sprintf(__('View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain'), $term->name) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
        if ($count != $i) {
            $term_list .= ' &middot; ';
        }
        else {
            $term_list .= '</p>';
        }
    }
    echo $term_list;
}
```

Comment: Please paste your code directly. Do not use images. Please file an [edit] and rectify